# Return an collection of elements from nested containers

Tags: containers, watin, element

I am trying to create a function that will return a collection of  elements (button) that are nested inside a series of containers.
ex: `[Span [Div [Button]]]`

The idea is I want to narrow down the button search to the nearest container that is identifiable/accessable.

If I pass the Span into a function as `IElementContainer` then I can see the buttons in the Span’s button
collection and get one using: `span.buttons(find.by..)` . Are the Div’s buttons accessable from the Span’s collection?
Would using  `Span.Elements`... be useful for digging into the inner DIv?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question you need to use the Filter method.
You can play with this syntax to get your buttons:

```
DivCollection divCol = session.browser.Span(Find.ByClass("classname")).DomContainer.Divs.Filter(Find.ByClass("className));
```

Using this div collection you can find your buttons.